# predict fails when execute from remote server

Tags: r, predict

I have this `R` code:

```
library(mongolite)

myUnserializationFunc<-function(value){
  return (unserialize(value,refhook = function(chr) list(dummy = 0L)))
}    

url_path = sprintf("mongodb+srv://%s:%s@%s", "someuser", "somepass", "somehost.in.mongodbatlas")

modelCollection<-mongo(collection = "somecollection"
                       ,url = paste0(url_path,"/","somedatabase"))    

modelName<-"modle32"
strConditions=paste0('{"modelName":"',modelName,'"}')
strSelect=paste0('{"object":true,"_id":false}')

mdl<-modelCollection$find(query=strConditions,fields=strSelect)
mdl<-myUnserializationFunc(mdl[[1]][[1]])


predict(mdl,iris)
```

It is working when I execute it from RStudio in my Windows local computer:

```
> predict(mdl,iris)
Using 100 trees...

  [1] 5.066186 4.766941 4.795193 4.910053 5.139620 5.554888 4.922106 4.967152 4.734696
 [10] 4.910053 5.230387 4.967152 4.766941 4.766941 5.139620 5.408491 5.317723 5.111907
 [19] 5.422505 5.276108 5.113549 5.408491 5.139620 5.210461 5.113549 4.857708 5.145256
 [28] 5.156954 4.876385 4.885961 4.910053 5.145256 5.230387 5.139620 4.910053 4.795193
 [37] 5.066186 5.139620 4.766941 4.967152 5.111907 4.651098 4.795193 5.335057 5.554888
```

However, I got this error when I execute the exactly the same script from a remote CentOS sever:

```
> stats::predict(mdl,iris)
Error in UseMethod("predict") :
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "gbm"
```

I tried also with Random Forest and I got the same error.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to load the package with that function.

Comment: Yep, I had to load the package of the type of model. In my case "gbm", so I had to include `library(gbm)` at the beginning of my script in remote server. dont want to post an answer?

Comment: OK. I was probably making the comment from an iPhone and couldn't test anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps needed to address a missing function begin with the name of the function. In this case you (or someone else) apparently put a full model object of class "gbm" into the database and then extracted it to a machine and session where the model-building function was not loaded into the workspace. Running a google search on `predict.gbm` brings up this as the first hit: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gbm/versions/2.1.8.1/topics/predict.gbm. So the first thing to try, which apparently succeeded for you, was to run `library(gbm)` prior to the call to `predict` on an object of that class. In the future you might consider naming your models with a string that includes either the class or the function name that produced that class of the object (often the same string).

Sometimes finding the correct package(s) may complicated by the fact that another method of storing the predict function is to embed it in the model object, but that will mostly be seen with pkg:caret-constructed class-"train" objects or perhaps with Bioconductor methods.